# TCP communication using VirtualBox

Tags: java, c, tcp, virtual-machine

I'm making a simple server program in host (Windows 10) and a client program in virtual machine (Ubuntu 22.04)
The server program receives an expression from a client, calculates it, and sends the result to the client,
and the client program sends an expression to a server, and receives the result from the server.

This is the server program written in Java.

```
package server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class TcpServer {
    
    private static final int SERVER_PORT = 8080;
    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Initialize server socket
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("created server socket");
        System.out.println("IPv4 address: " + serverSocket.getInetAddress());
        System.out.println("port number: " + serverSocket.getLocalPort());
        
        try {
            System.out.println("waiting");
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("connected");
            process(clientSocket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private static void process(Socket clientSocket) {
        try (
                InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
                ) {
            String expression = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("expression: " + expression);
            String result = calculate(expression);
            System.out.println("answer: " + result);
            bufferedWriter.write(result);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            System.out.println("sended result");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private static String calculate(String expression) {
        ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine scriptEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = (String) scriptEngine.eval(expression);
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return result;
    }

}
```

And this is the client program written in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

void error_handling(char *message);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char result[1024] = {'\0'};
    int str_len;
   
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage : %s <IP> <port> \n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
   
    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   
    if (sock == -1) {
        error_handling("socket() error");
    }
   
    memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
   
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1) {
        error_handling("connect() error!");
    }
    printf("connected");
    
    char expr[1024];
    printf("enter expression.\n");
    fgets(expr, 1024, stdin);
    if (send(sock, expr, 1024, 0) == -1) {
        printf("send() error");
    }
   
    if (recv(sock, result, 1024, 0) == -1) {
        error_handling("read() error!");
    }
       
    printf("Message from server: %s \n", result);
   
    close(sock);
   
    return 0;
}

void error_handling(char *message) {
    fputs(message, stderr);
    fputc('\n', stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

I checked VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter of VirtuaBox and it was like this:

```
Adapter
IPv4 address: 192.168.56.1
IPv4 subnet mask: 255.255.255.0

DHCP server (Enabled)
Server address: 192.168.56.100
Server mask: 255.255.255.0
Lowest address: 192.168.56.101
Highest address: 192.168.56.254
```

And I checked Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machine's network configuration and it was like this:

```
Adapter #1: enabled
Connected to NAT

Adapter #2: enabled
Connected to Host-Only Adapter
Name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
```

I checked 'ipconfig' in host(Windows 10) and it was like this:

```
Ethernet Adapter Ethernet
~~~
   IPv4 Address . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
~~~
```

And checked 'ifconfig' in virtual machine(Ubuntu 22.04) and it was like this:

```
enp0s8: ...
    inet 192.168.56.101 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

I executed the server program and the client program, but the server program prints "created server socket ~~~ port number: 8080", the client program prints nothing, and no more happens.

I executed Wireshark and checked Ethernet.

```
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 58930, Dst Port: 8080, Seq: 0, Len: 0
```

It seems that any connection is not made between the server and the client. What should I do to make a connection between them?

I checked "ipconfig" in the host, "ifconfig" in the VM and Wireshark.
The server program is expected to print "connected" and the client program is expected to get an expression but none of them happens.

Comment: Where did you run Wireshark - in the host or VM? You probably have a firewall running on one or both of your systems that may block this traffic.

Comment: Expanding on what pmacfarlane said, check that your firewalls are allowing traffic. In shell windows on both windows and ubuntu, can you `ping` the other system? Can you run `firefox` under ubuntu and connect to the internet (e.g. `www.cnn.com`)? Under ubuntu, can you `telnet` into the windows server? The `java` server seems to have an awful lot of complexity. Since you're writing the client in C, could you write the server in C as well? What are the exact commands given in a shell prompt (both systems) to invoke the requisite programs?

Comment: I runned Wireshark on host. I runned server on Eclipse IDE using `Ctrl + F11`. I runned client with command `./tcp_client 192.168.56.1 8080`. I tried `ping 192.168.56.1` on VM and got `64 bytes from192.168.56.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.99 ms`
--------------------------------------

While writing this comment, I checked the firewall and turned it off. After doing so, everything worked well. It turns out the firewall was the cause. Thank you for your help.